# How to adjust the default _ttl value on a DynamoDB table (when deleting with AppSync, using AWS Amplify)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

When I delete an item using AppSync (or DataStore) on an AWS Amplify app, it makes two changes to the DynamoDB item:

1. The `delete` field is set to true
2. A `_ttl` field is added, and a timestamp value is provided of 1 month in the future.

According to the [AppSync conflict detection documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/conflict-detection-and-sync.html#versioned-data-sources), the value is configured on the `DeltaSyncTableTTL` value, which is configured on the data source:

> `_ttl`
>
> - A numeric value that stores the timestamp, in epoch seconds,
>   when an item should be removed from the Delta table. This value is
>   determined by adding the DeltaSyncTableTTL value configured on the
>   data source to the moment when the change occurred. This field should
>   be configured as the DynamoDB TTL Attribute.

If I go to my AppSync console, and navigate to 'Data Sources' in the left panel, I'm provided with links to my DynamoDB data sources. But I can't find any settings anywhere in the AppSync or DynamoDB consoles to update a `DeltaSyncTableTTL` value.

Answer (score 2):

To update the "Base table time to live", go to your AppSync console and click 'Data Sources' on the panel on the left side of the page.

Then, select the datasource/dynamodb table by clicking the round checkbox to the left of the data source and click the 'Edit' button above.

Scroll down to the following and adjust as required:

[image]